# USB 2.0 external 5.25" enclosure doesn't show up in Windows Explorer

Tags: external-drive

I am running Windows 10 on a HP EliteBook 650 G9 laptop.  I plugged in a Vantec NexStar DX external 5.2" enclosure.  It doesn't show up in Windows Explorer.  I used Disk Management to see that it seems to be mapped to letter drive "D".  Rebooting doesn't help.  I've tried several written discs in the drive and also tried connecting the drive to a 2nd laptop (also Windows 10).

Is there anything specific that I need to do to have the drive recognized in Windows Explorer?

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot of Disk Management doesn't show any other disk than Disk 0 or anything mapped to D. Your description seems like a classical case of a dead disk.

Comment: I guess the CD-ROM 0 isn't the external enclosure?  I don't understand how multiple discs written years apart can be dead.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: No, the CD-ROM isn't the external enclosure. No disk is eternal, and some are less so than others. The lifetime of a disk is a matter of initial manufacturing quality, its handling, and then of pure luck.

Comment: Shouldn't the enclosure at least show up as a device?  (P.S. I'm off to purchase a more modern external DVD drive, but it might be for nothing of all the discs are bad)

Comment: Excuse me - I misunderstood. You're really asking about a CD-ROM? In that case my comment above is only partially true. Try several CDs and several USB ports on your computer and on others. If the results are the same, this external CD-ROM drive is defective.

Comment: Actually, your post title seems to conflict with what you're saying. Now, what is this: A USB disk or a CD-ROM?

Comment: If the D drive is the CD-ROM, and it says no media, Explorer will hide empty drives by default. Ensure that the drive contains a CD that it can read, and it should show up, assuming the drive itself is not faulty.

Comment: @LPChip: I saw what you described once I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was connecting the external enclosure to USB 2.0 ports. When I connect the enclosure to a USB 3.0 port, the drive shows up ad "DVD RD Drive (D:)" in File Explorer. It is taking a long time to read, judging from the progress indicator at the top of the File Explorer window. Still reading, for about 5-10 minutes now.  Essentially, the external enclosure shows up as a drive, but I can't descend into it until it has a readable disc.

Comment: @harrymc: It's a 5.25" optical disc drive enclosure. The disc itself could be a CD-ROM or a write-able disc. Note that these discs have "CD-R" imprinted on the top-side and I presume that this is because I can't rewrite to the same area on the disc.  However, I can add to the disc by writing successive sessions, but prefer not to because the bookkeeping has confused readers in the past. The connection to the laptop is via USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was connecting the external enclosure to the laptop's USB 2.0 ports.  When I connected it to the USB 3.0 port, the drive was visible in Widows Explorer.  I couldn't descend into it without a readable disc in the drive.

As it turns out, most of the discs were unreadable.  After checking [this site](https://www.canada.ca/en/conservation-institute/services/conservation-preservation-publications/canadian-conservation-institute-notes/longevity-recordable-cds-dvds.html) on data longevity, I suspected that the problem was with the drive rather than the discs.  I tried a brand new optical drive that I just bought, and it worked fine.

In case it helps others troubleshoot in the future, I find that the external drive shows up in Windows Explorer *after* a readable disc as been detected in the drive.  The drive's presence persists in Windows Explorer even after the disc has been removed.